# Debian - /usr/bin/env: 'php\r': No such file or directory

Tags: php, docker, yii2, debian

So go straight to the problem, when I run `./yii` seems I got that error from Debian:stretch that I ran from Docker.

However when I run `/usr/bin/env php -v` I got the correct output and there's no problem on it.

Seems there's a problem on new line being translated as string and I have no idea how to fix it.

Sorry if my English a bit messy and thanks in advance.

Just note:

- I've been trying to edit that file using `nano` within debian but it's useless. I'm getting the same error.
- I've check php file within `/usr/bin/php` and it's exist both `php` and `php7.1`
- I can run `php -v` without problem as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should convert the file with UNIX new line convention.

You have a DOS file, which has the extra `\r` character before `\n`, which is interpreted as a character in the command. So system will check the program `php\r` and not `php`, and so it fails.

```
tr -d '\15' < original_file > converted_file
```

should do the work (StackOverflow has many other methods and tricks)

Comment: Thanks. This solved. Is there any more easy way instead rewriting each files?

Comment: You should google. There are many tools, but it depends on your systems, preferences, etc.  If you use git (or other code repositories), they can translate files for you (both way, so you do not mess other systems). FTP and similar should be able also to convert file on copying. Linux has various tools to convert files in a tree, I just do not remember, and you need to install the relevant package. Some editors have options to convert files (e.g. when doing a "upload"). Google will help

Comment: Works, but make sure that original_file != converted_file