# PHP CLI script errors after git commit

Tags: php, windows, git

I have a CLI script with the ff. on top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// ...
```

The script works however after I `git commit`, running the same script again returns the ff. error:

> /usr/bin/env: 'php\r': No such file or directory

The script is fixed by doing the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794312).

My question is how do I prevent this issue from happening in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there's a git config that is changing EOL format to CRLF instead of keeping LF. It's a whole topic. Long-story short, if you want git to not mess with EOL format of files, set this on .gitattributes:

```
* -text
```

With that you are telling git not to mess up with the EOL format of any file in the project. Add the file to the project so that it can be shared by all developers. Finally, if the commit that is messing up with the file is the last one, amend it (after adjusting the file to have unix EOL and have the attribute set on .gitattributes):

```
dos2unix the-script.php
git add the-script.php
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Comment: Doing `git config --list` shows these `core.autocrlf=true` `core.safecrlf=false` does these have anything to do with this issue?

Comment: Yep... both... and they are a mess. Use the attribute and then you are in control.